# Responsive circle that maintains aspect ratio when shrunk

Tags: css, responsive-design, resize, responsive

I've made a circle, but I want it to maintain the 1:1 aspect ratio when it's shrunk down so it doesn't look like an oval on mobile

html:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='circle'></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/drhectapus/pen/aWMgZx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `padding-bottom` aspect ratio trick ([read more](https://mademyday.de/height-equals-width-with-pure-css/)) to get the circle to maintain its 1:1 ratio.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.circle::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could specify your circle's width and height in `vw` (viewport width) units, to have the element maintain the same relative width and height as your browser resizes - like `width: 10vw; height: 10vw;`.

Comment: thank you! your solution is the only one I could find that preserves the aspect ratio of the circle, and also the relative horizontal alignment of other elements (text in my case) below the circle. Fixing width and height in vw units preserves the circle aspect ratio, but breaks horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Make the cirlcle a flex and set `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` to 0.

html:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='circle'></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  border: 2px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;

  // add these two lines
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

This will make the circle a flex and prevent it from growing or shrinking. Thus maintaining the aspect ratio.